# ReadProcessMemory char array, hex output to int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am using ReadProcessMemory, well to read process memory.  I am looking at a spot which contains a value 3325.  However, I am looking at memory in a hex viewer and the value is displayed as FD0C = 0CFD = 3325.  So when I read the value into my char array and then try and convert (atoi) I am getting junk.  I am new to c++ and I am wondering if there is a function that would do the conversion or am I going to have to write it myself (which I don't mind)?

```
    char num_char[16];
    _stackstart = _start + 0x28;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(void *)_stackstart, &num_char, 4, &lpRead);
    x = ...some conversion(num_char);
    if(stack != x)
    {tell me;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` only works for decimal numbers. Use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) instead and pass a base value of 16 to convert hexadecimal numbers:

```
x = strtol(num_char, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Its little endian, is there a way to get it to read the array right to left?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you post and your description, it doesn't look like you are dealing with a string of ascii characters, but rather a buffer caintining a binary number. To convert the raw binary value into an integer you merely need to cast it to the correct value. Note that you have to be careful to cast it to the integer type that is the correct size. You only list 2 bytes in your example number, but you are reading 4.

For Visual Studio 2008, where an int or long is 4-byte integer, you can simply do this:

```
int x = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(num_char);
```

Note that to be more portable, you should use a type that is guaranteed to be 4 bytes. In Visual C++ you can use DWORD. Though the preferred solution would be to use int32_t from [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h), though that is not available with Visual Studio before version Visual Studio 2010.

Also, you don't mention if your type is signed or unsigned, if it is unsigned, then use an unsigned type.